# How to remove one single element from the navbar after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a logo in my navbar. But after scrolling down the page, the navbar remains fixed to the top. But I want to remove the logo after scrolldown as it takes up too much space. I want it to be just the part of the navbar when the page is scrolled up to the top. How to remove it using Javascript?

```js
var prev = 0;
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('#logo');

$window.on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
  nav.toggleClass('hidden', scrollTop > prev);
  prev = scrollTop;
});
```

```css
*{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
  <img id="logo" src="">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-main-collapse">
  </div>
</div>
```

(**I have inserted the `*{}` so that its clear to understand the layout*).

Comment: Please post the JS code for your latest attempt

Comment: You can identify "position: relative;" rule to navbar-header class. It would be better if you can provide your style codes.

Comment: you can do this with jquery by using the .hide() function but the most better option is to remove the logo from your theme sticky header setting.

Comment: This looks like what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556390/logo-at-the-top-of-navigation-bar-hide-when-scroll-down

Answer (score 1):

Use the below jquery code to hide image on the scroll.

```
window.onscroll = function (e)
{
    $('#logo').hide();
}
```